# Sum a row of cells based on string texts to the right of the numerical cell

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula, worksheet-function, sumifs

I have inherited a monthly leave spreadsheet for employees. The spreadsheet includes all types of leave, including sick leave, for each day of that month. Each manager completes the spreadsheet by indicating the number of hours in the first column under the specific date. The next column under the day indicates the code for the type of leave, i.e. certified sick leave is `csl`, whereas uncertified sick leave is `us`.

Please see sample of spreadsheet:

```
1st     2nd     3rd     4th     5th     6th     7th     8th     9th 

H   C   H   C   H   C   H   C   H   C   H   C   H   C   H   C   H   C

11  TIL 11  TIL         11  AL  8.5 AL  8.5 AL  8.5 AL
```

I am looking to sum the total number of hours in each row based on the text string in the column to the right of the numerical value. This code can reoccur on a number of occasions across each row.

Comment: Please format your spreadsheet data so that it is readable.  As it stands now, your question and your data do not agree.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=SUMIFS($A:$K,$B:$L,"TIL")
```

and

```
=SUMIFS($A:$K,$B:$L,"AL")
```

and other codes to suit.

Comment: Thanks for that pnuts. That did the job.